# pyexcel.exceptions.UnknownParameters error after bundling with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyexcel

I am trying to convert a python file to .exe using pyinstaller with the following command. Please suggest what is wrong with this approach.

```
pyinstaller.exe --hidden-import pyexcel --hidden-import pyexcel-io --hidden-import pyexcel_xls --hidden-import pyexcel_xlsx -F FormatBuster.py
```

The project have additional imports of pyexcel_xls, pyexcel_xlsx which is being handled with --hidden-import arguments. I am getting the following error when the .exe is run, however when the .py file is executed directly, it is working perfectly.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "FormatBuster.py", line 90, in <module>
File "site-packages\pyexcel\core.py", line 36, in get_sheet
File "site-packages\pyexcel\internal\core.py", line 19, in get_sheet_stream
File "site-packages\pyexcel\internal\source_plugin.py", line 76, in get_source
File "site-packages\pyexcel\internal\source_plugin.py", line 65, in get_a_plugin
File "site-packages\pyexcel\internal\source_plugin.py", line 48, in load_me_now
File "site-packages\pyexcel\internal\source_plugin.py", line 138, in _error_handler
pyexcel.exceptions.UnknownParameters: Please check if there were typos in function parameters: {'file_name': 'C:\\Users\\kiranv1\\Documents\\R&D\\FormatBuster\\input\\DDVIJAYA_13_Apr_2018_Lot_1.xls'}. Otherwise unrecognized parameters were given.
[146004] Failed to execute script FormatBuster
```

The python file uses a .config file whose contents are as shown below

```
{
"params":{
    "inputpath":"C:\\Users\\kiranv1\\Documents\\R&D\\FormatBuster\\input",
    "outputpath":"C:\\Users\\kiranv1\\Documents\\R&D\\FormatBuster\\output",
    "logpath":"C:\\Users\\kiranv1\\Documents\\R&D\\FormatBuster\\output",
    "files": {
        "DDVIJAYA" : {
            "Due Date":"T2D",
            "Instalment No.":"T2N",
            "Instalment Amount":"T2N"
        }           
    }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding answer as the Issue got resolved. The error occured due to missing dependency modules for PyExcel. The following github page list out all the dependencies required for packaging. [PyExcel Dependency List for packaging](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-io/blob/master/docs/source/pyinstaller.rst)

Updated pyinstaller code is as given below

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --log-level=DEBUG ^
--onefile ^
--hidden-import pyexcel_io.readers.csvr
--hidden-import pyexcel_io.readers.csvz
--hidden-import pyexcel_io.readers.tsv
--hidden-import pyexcel_io.readers.tsvz
--hidden-import pyexcel_io.writers.csvw
--hidden-import pyexcel_io.readers.csvz
--hidden-import pyexcel_io.readers.tsv
--hidden-import pyexcel_io.readers.tsvz
--hidden-import pyexcel_io.database.importers.django
--hidden-import pyexcel_io.database.importers.sqlalchemy
--hidden-import pyexcel_io.database.exporters.django
--hidden-import pyexcel_io.database.exporters.sqlalchemy
--hidden-import pyexcel_xlsx
--hidden-import pyexcel_xlsx.xlsxr
--hidden-import pyexcel_xlsx.xlsxw
--hidden-import pyexcel_xlsxw
--hidden-import pyexcel_xlsxw.xlsxw
--hidden-import pyexcel_xls
--hidden-import pyexcel_xls.xlsr
--hidden-import pyexcel_xls.xlsw
FormatBuster.py
```